# Finding influential characteristics in a chain of events

Tags: classification, bayesian, clustering, markov-process, rare-events

I have some data which is sequences of actions performed by individuals. All of these actions have properties (some catagorical, some binary, some continuous numeric). Individuals can have 1 to unbounded actions (but usually no more than 10). Some of these actions contain a positive outcome (a fairly rare event - around 1/1000 events have positive outcome). There can be any length of time between the events.

I want to work out if there are any properties of the history of the actions of an individual which make it more likely there will be a positive outcome (at the current action, or maybe ever, whichever is easier). **In human terms, I want to know what an event stream that will end in a positive outcome "looks like".**

I've tried logistical regression predicting the outcome of a single event, with features made from the characteristics of that event and its predecessor (if there was one).

Does anybody know of other methods which might be suitable? It feels like it might be a Markov chain problem (I can perhaps calculate transition probabilities between events of different types). Or Bayesian, because I want to know what the chances of the positive event are given the history. Or classification, because I want to predict positive event occurrence from the property of the event chain. It might have unsupervised learning elements, if it's worth clustering the event chains initially, and seeing if membership of a given cluster is a good predictor of positive event occurrence.

For any technique I would have to sub-sample the negative cases, as there is a lot of data, so any advice on how to correctly sample events which are grouped in chains is also welcome. And in consequence, how to know which elements of the analysis are not immediately translatable to the whole population because they were calculated on a sample.